How to Update Previous Card in Google Apps Script
I'm currently making a Gmail Google Add-on but I'm confused about using card navigation in Apps Script. What I intend is to have Card A, Card B, and Card C in sequence, and when a button is pressed on Card C, Card C is poped and previous Card B should be updated to a Card B'
[Card A, Card B, Card C] -> [Card A, Card B`]
Below is the example code which works same as mine
function buildCardA() {
  var card = CardService.newCardBuilder()
      .setHeader(CardService.newCardHeader().setTitle("Card A"))
      .addSection(
        CardService.newCardSection()
        .addWidget(
          CardService.newTextButton()
          .setText('Go to Card B')
          .setOnClickAction(CardService.newAction()
            .setFunctionName('goToCardB'))
        )
      )
      .build();
  return card;
}

function buildCardB() {
  var card = CardService.newCardBuilder()
      .setHeader(CardService.newCardHeader().setTitle("Card B"))
      .addSection(
        CardService.newCardSection()
        .addWidget(
          CardService.newTextButton()
          .setText('Go to Card C')
          .setOnClickAction(CardService.newAction()
            .setFunctionName('goToCardC'))
        )
      )
      .build();
  return card;
}

function buildCardC() {
  var card = CardService.newCardBuilder()
      .setHeader(CardService.newCardHeader().setTitle("Card C"))
      .addSection(
        CardService.newCardSection()
        .addWidget(
          CardService.newTextButton()
          .setText('Pop and Update Card B')
          .setOnClickAction(CardService.newAction()
            .setFunctionName('handleCardCButtonClick'))
        )
      )
      .build();
  return card;
}

function goToCardB() {
  var cardB = buildCardB();
  return CardService.newNavigation().pushCard(cardB);
}

function goToCardC() {
  var cardC = buildCardC();
  return CardService.newNavigation().pushCard(cardC);
}

function handleCardCButtonClick(e) {
  var updatedCardB = CardService.newCardBuilder()
      .setHeader(CardService.newCardHeader().setTitle("Updated Card B"))
      .addSection(
        CardService.newCardSection()
        .addWidget(
          CardService.newTextParagraph().setText("This is the updated content of Card B.")
        )
      )
      .build();

  return CardService.newNavigation()  //Modified Part
      .popCard()
      .updateCard(updatedCardB)
}

function onHomepage(e) {
  var cardA = buildCardA();
  return CardService.newActionResponseBuilder()
      .setNavigation(CardService.newNavigation().pushCard(cardA))
      .build();
}

However, navigation doesn't work for what I intended. For changing the modified part of the above code,
return CardService.newNavigation()
      .popCard()
      .updateCard(updatedCardB)

and
return CardService.newNavigation()
      .popToRoot()
      .updateCard(updatedCardB)

results [Card A, Card B, Card B`],
return CardService.newNavigation()
      .popCard()
      .popCard()
      .pushCard(updatedCardB)

and
return CardService.newNavigation()
      .popToRoot()
      .pushCard(updatedCardB)

results [Card A, Card B, Card C, Card B`]
I've tried other attempts, but they didn't work as what I intended. How can I make the code work resulting [Card A, Card B`]?
